# DropdownModule not rendering as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-cli, primeng

I created a dropdown using DropdownModule. The dropdown renders but not as expected as shown below:

[image]

### typescript

```
export const countryListOfObjects: SelectItem[]
    = [
  { label: 'Select a country', value: null },
  //A
  { label: 'Albania', value: { name: 'Albania', code: '' } },
  { label: 'Algeria', value: { name: 'Algeria', code: '' } },
  {
    label: 'American Samoa', value: { name: 'American Samoa', code: '' }
...]
```

### html

```
  <p-dropdown [options] = 'countries'
                            [(ngModel)] = 'address.country'
                            formControlName = 'country'
                            [filter] = 'true'
                            ></p-dropdown>
```

Removing the filter binding results in the same display.

I am using angular2-final and the current release of primeng. No errors relating to primeng are seen except for the following

client?93b6:76 [default] Z:\node_modules\primeng\components\fileupload\fileupload.d.ts:2:9 
Module '"J:/workspace/angular2/ts/epimss/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'DomSanitizer'.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the `primeng` style sheet links in your index.html?

Comment: They were included in the angular-cli "styles": [..] key as suggested here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514408/angular-cli-primeng-require-is-not-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514408/angular-cli-primeng-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Interesting. For me, when I added the theme and the main css, the dropdown started rendering properly. I added them via the index.html, though.

Comment: Initially I added them to index.html, but then angular2 complained that they could not be resolved. I found the article and followed the instruction and they were found. Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: I am not use the CLI for the project that I have been testing `primeng` with. But I have used the CLI, and added CSS to the project via the index.html, without issue. With the CLI, it adds the `moduleId: module.id` to components, which allows for relative paths to styles and templates. That may be part of the issue. Worth checking out.

Comment: With the latest final release module.id has be removed from all components.

Comment: Check out this self-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551786/primeng-beta-15-angular-2-datatable-not-rendering-with-styling. No luck with the component styles there either. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a CSS issue.

You need to use a bunch of css sheets, particularly primeng's and font awesome.

This is how my angular-cli.json looks like

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ]
```

I had an issue when trying to import primeng.css, it complained about loading.gif. So i commented that line inside the css.

If you are not using the angular cli, you can just import those in index.html.

Edit: If you are using bootstrap css it will mess up primeng's dropdown.